# How to add a toolbar above the keyboard

Tags: swiftui

[image]

It's possible to create a Toolbar above keyboard in UIKit using the inputAccessoryView. But how can that be done for SwiftUI? Since, inputAccessoryView isn't supported for SwiftUI (Based on what I looked up online). I have limited knowledge on UIKit and Objective-C so not sure how I can combine SwiftUI and UIKit

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct TipsView: View {
    @State private var amount = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section (header: Text("Amount")) {
                    HStack (spacing: 1) {
                        if !amount.isEmpty {
                            Text("£")
                        }
                        TextField("Amount", text: $amount)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .onReceive(Just(amount)) { newValue in
                                let filtered = newValue.filter { "0123456789.".contains($0)}
                                if filtered != newValue {
                                    amount = filtered
                                }
                            }
                    }//HStack
                }//Section
            }//Form
        }//NavigationView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap a `UITextField` inside a `UIViewRepresentable` and then add a toolbar to the `UITextField`.

For instance

```swift
struct WrappedTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    // binding...
    
    typealias UIViewType = UITextField
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        // update binding...
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    
    public class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        // delegate methods...
    }
}

extension UITextField {

    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard(){
        let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        doneToolbar.barStyle = .default
        
        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonAction))
        
        let items = [flexSpace, done]
        doneToolbar.items = items
        doneToolbar.sizeToFit()
        
        self.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
    }
    
    @objc func doneButtonAction(){
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to use it like a normal SwiftUI view

```swift
var body: some View {
   WrappedTextField(...)
}
```

To see examples of how to create `UIViewRepresentable`s checkout my repo [here](https://github.com/youjinp/swiftuikit)

Comment: To be a useful answer, also for other readers, can you add the actual code for this specific example, instead of a link?

Comment: This does NOT cover moving to NEXT and/or PREVIOUS fields as OP asked!

Comment: The question was "How to add a toolbar above the keyboard" and not "how to move next and/or previous fields"

Answer (score 1):

### iOS 15+

```
TextField("Amount", text: $amount)
    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            Spacer()
            Button("Done") {
                print("...")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its available in IOS15+

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I adjusted it